# How to obtain report URL from SSRS .rdlc report?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I'm looking for a way to obtain the report URL from within an SSRS report that is defined locally in an ASP.NET web application. I've tried using the `Globals!ReportServerUrl` Built-in field, but its not giving me anything useful ( just shows as #ERROR when I place the value in a text box ). I guess this is to be expected since the report doesn't actually live on report server and is defined locally in the app. Any input would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `.rdlc` reports are rendered **locally** - not on a server .... so what URL are you talking about exactly???

Comment: Indeed they are, I'm simply looking for the URL of the report. I'm trying to avoid passing it in via a parameter but it looks like that might be my only option...

Comment: Are you thinking of its URL as being the path through your web app to the report?  Because, as @marc_s points out, if the reports are local, they are by definition not on a server, so there is no meaningful `ReportServerUrl`.

Comment: Yea sort of, I was hoping there would be someway to access the Request string from within the report (like you can do in a ASP.NET Page object) other than just passing it in as a parameter. I really just need the domain of request, but it's not looking like there is any way to do that.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by accessing the Request URL?? As I said - those RDLC reports are rendered locally, without a report server - so there is no URL to use ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, RDLC is rendered "locally". This -confusingly- *may be* on a server, but will still not have a *Report* Server URL (which is the cause for the error).

**In the report** you have **no obvious way to find any HttpContext items** like the request URL, which you seem to be after.

Simplest solution is probably to [create a report parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337432%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) `@RequestUrl` and pass [something from the HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.request%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) into it.

(There's also [Custom Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx), which you could try, but I doubt it has access to the request URL.)

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure there was any way to get context, I guess there is not. I've gone ahead and just parametrized the URL in my procedure so the link can be built to send the user back to the same server they "came" from.